# Custom Intellisense Auto Complete

Tags: c#, visual-studio, autocomplete, intellisense

Is it possible to add custom Intellisense to autocomplete my strings?

**Example:**

I type 
"Ada

it will popup intellisense  ->Adapt , ->Adapter , ...

I'm working with a new language and would require to add more function to Visual Studio 2015's library. Having an autocomplete with my database of keywords would speed up coding and efficiency.

Is there anyway to do so without using external programs?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found out a way after all.

Proceed to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372314.aspx and go through the walkthrough, linking a content type to a file name.