# Is it possible to add custom autocomplete keywords to IntelliSense?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

I've been working in C#, with Visual Studio and IntelliSense.

We have a method that we utilize a lot in our classes that gets called by our main system through reflection.

Since it's being called using reflection, when you are typing the method there is no auto-complete suggestion to help you avoid mistakes when typing the method's name.

Question is, is it possible to customize IntelliSense (or any other similar tool) so that when the user wants to create a new method called e.g. `public void CalledThroughReflectionMethod()` they would get the autocomplete suggestion after they have typed `public void C`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom Intellisense Auto Complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39569157/) [Custom Intellisense Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460138/) and [Custom IntelliSense system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53262028/) and [Custom Editor with Intellisense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40382654/) and [How to get intellisense for custom created classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240402/)

Comment: please post the reflection call of the method. It sound like you could use `nameof`. Also it is yet unclear why you would need to use reflection at all if you know at compile time what method you want to call